# I want for each choice of my entityType to show many propreties of that choice Symfony 4

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, symfony-forms, twig-extension

Here's my problem, I am working with Symfony 4. I created a form and added a collection of another form type. It worked perfectly but now, I want to change the Collection into a EntityType.

Here's my first code

```php
$builder
    ->add('id_etudiant', EtudiantSecondType::class)
    ->add('id_diplome', DiplomeType::class)
    ->add('suivres', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => SuivreType::class,
        'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
    ]) ;
```

And now I want to change it in something like this

```php
$builder
    ->add('id_etudiant', EtudiantSecondType::class)
    ->add('id_diplome', DiplomeType::class)
    ->add('suivres', EntityType::class, [
        'class' =>SuivreType::class,
        'block_name'=>'app_one_module_type',
        'block_prefix'=>'app_one_module',
        'mapped'=>false,
        'expanded'=>true,
        'multiple'=>true,
        'choice_label'=>function(Suivre  $suivre){
            return "";
        },
    ])
;
```

I don't think we can specify the form type in the EntityType so I added the twig parts i need but it doesn't work. I get results but not in the twig format I declared in:

```php
'block_name'=>'app_one_module_type',
'block_prefix'=>'app_one_module',
```

Comment: the class of the entityType is Suivre not SuivreType

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand the problem exactly. Why did you change from CollectionType to EntityType? How is it rendered right now and how should it be instead, e.g. "Right now it's a _combobox of entity names_, but I want it to be ..."?

Comment: Before changing to the combobox , i was showing for each element of the Collection an app_one_module part

{% block app_one_module_widget %}

 <tr {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
    <th scope="row">
        {{ form_widget(form.idModule.libelle, {'attr' : { 'placeholder' : 'app.form.label.libelle'|trans , 'class' : 'form-control' , 'readonly' :'true' }}) }}
...
..
.
{% endblock app_one_module_widget %}







I want to show this exact part for each choice of entityType but instead it only shows boxes

Comment: I hope I'am making since, I'm not very good with english

Comment: Don't worry. We'll get there. Feel free to edit your question and add the template snippet as well. I think that will help. Have you tried setting the [`expanded`-option](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#expanded) on your EntityType? That should replace the combobox with radio buttons (if I am not mistaken) for each entry.